# ReactJS - Can't access properties in object from a fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm doing a fetch to an API and it's returning the data fine, but when I try access the properties, it returns:

*Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {breeds, categories, id, url, width, height}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

**myFetch.jsx**

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class myFetch extends Component {

    state={
        data:[]
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        const url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        fetch(url)
        .then(r=>r.json())
        .then(data=>{
            this.setState({data:data})

            // console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e))
    }



    render(){

        const {data} = this.state
        console.log(data[0])
        return (<p>{data[0]}</p>)
    }
}

export default myFetch
```

**EDIT**

"data" in the state is initialized to an array. Therefore, I should have iterated through the array during the render as
{data.map(d => d.url)} and access whichever property I desire as shown below:

```
render(){

    const {data} = this.state
    console.log(data)
    return (<p>{data.map(d=>d.url)}</p>)
}
```

Comment: What's your interpretation of that error message? Because it seems very clear to me.

Comment: maybe it is can be done with { data.length && <p> data[0] </p> } if it is only that at initialstate data has no props...





can you copy  { consoloe.log(data[0]) } or { // console.log(data)} ?

Comment: It seems clear to me too, but when I tried accessing the properties during the render, it didn't work. What I did was return the array during the fetch call as "this.setState({data:data[0]})". It works now, but only if I return the data during the fetch. Is there a way to return the data during the render?

Comment: What do you mean *"accessing the properties during the render"*? What happened exactly? And was that when data[0] was still undefined?

Comment: @HagaiHarari I did a console.log(data[0]) and it returns the object, when I try to access the properties, for example: console.log(data[0].url) then I get an error : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see the data when I access the data as {data[0]}, however, if I try to access the properties as {data[0].id}, then I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"

Comment: Because before the fetch finishes it *is* undefined, you just need to guard against that case.

Comment: it seems like the response isnt [array], which you refer with  { array[index] }, it is {object} which you refer with { object.prop }. 

try { console.log(data.url) } instead, and change your initialstate to { data: {} } for consistency. in case you have reason why store data as array, at response map through response and push args one by one to array

Comment: @jonrsharpe The fetch is finished, once the data is sent to the state, I try to access it during the render and it returns undefined.

Comment: @HagaiHarari I see! I was initializing the data incorrectly. Instead of [], I should initiate it into a an empty object {}. I'm still unclear when to use an empty array or an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

Your data on the state doesn't have any element on 0 index. That's why you getting that undefined error. You can check if it exists before trying to render it.

Something like that:

```
render() {
const { data } = this.state;
if (data[0]) {
  console.log(data[0]);
  return <p>{data[0].url}</p>;
}
return null;
```

}